# Can't import and use object in Scala worksheet

Tags: scala

I have an object `MyObject` that generate dummy data in a project `myProject`.

In the same directory, I created a worksheet to see what data is generated by `MyObject`.

I have the following code:

```
import myProject.MyObject


val loans = MyObject.generateLoans(3)


loans
```

For this code, I am getting these errors:

```
Error:object MyObject is not a member of package myProject
import myProject.MyObject
       ^
Error:(4, 19) not found: value MyObject
lazy val loans = MyObject.generateLoans(3)
                 ^
Error:(12, 50) object MyObject is not a member of package myProject
println(MacroPrinter210.printImportInfo({import myProject.MyObject;}))
                                                ^
```

These errors don't make much sense, as `MyObject` is actually part of `myProject`.

Comment: Could you give an overview of your file structure, and in which directory you run the compiler?

Comment: so how did you solve it?